# How to manage a SaaS project

Tags: android, ios, git, react-native, saas

We have a repo that contains a Base code for a React Native App (SaaS)

In the same Repo, We have multiple branches for every client (separated app)

Master contains the main base code (we push any new features/ fixes to it)

Now we have issues when want to push the new features/fixes to other branches! It's about changing the package name and icons etc (native stuff). When open PR to take updates from master => client-1.

So do you recommend any tips that help us to manage all fixes/features in the base code and applying it to other branches without effected by iOS/Android things?

Answer (score 0):

This is potentially an insufficiently specific question but, I'll try to help.

The way I'd approach this is just having develop, staging, and main branches, so I can minimize the conflict potential. In what I assume is a monorepo, I'd then be able to accomplish having base changes get to the client apps in some orchestrated manner, via localized package management by way of leveraging Lerna or Yalc, plus a CI/CD step. In effect, I'd have any changes to base cause an associated version bump of "base" in the dependent clients, and a rebuild + release of those clients.